# Control where method documentation goes for simple generic, while hiding from package index

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen2

I'm writing an R package and largely following Hadley's book on the topic. I'm running into a problem with documenting methods for simple generics like print, plot, head, and tail. When I use the @describeIn tag to control where the method documentation goes, I get the nice feature of them showing up in the help file for the main analysis function that returns an object of the given class. The problem is that these generics also show up in the package's index. If I add `@keywords internal` to the generics, then they are removed from the package's index, but so is the main analysis function (they are in the same .R file). If I document the generics in a separate .R file, then I can gain control over what is and is not in the package's index, but I have two issues: the main analysis function doesn't come first in the Usage section of the help file; and if add the `@keywords internal` for the generics, this removes the analysis function from the package index too, even though they are documented (in this instance) in separate files. The crux of the problem seems to be that `@keywords internal` applies to all functions in the given .R file, and maybe even any function referenced in `@describeIn`, while `@describeIn` is designed for documenting multiple functions in a given .R file.

For now, I have the analysis function and generics in the same .R file to control where the method documention goes and its ordering in the Usage section, but am not using `@keywords internal` and leaving the index cluttered.

Here's a rough sketch of an exported analysis function:

```
#' @inheritParams foo
#' @export
seats <- function(judgeit.object, ...) {
[...omitted...]
class(out.object) <- "judgeit.seats"
return(out.object)
}
```

And a generic:

```
#' @describeIn seats Print a \code{\link{seats}} output
#' @keywords internal
#' @export
print.judgeit.seats <- function(x,...) print(x$output,...)
```

I want the help file for `?seats` to look like this:

```
seats(judgeit.object, ...)

## S3 method for class 'judgeit.seats'
print(x, ...)

## S3 method for class 'judgeit.seats'
head(x, ...)

## S3 method for class 'judgeit.seats'
tail(x, ...)
```

I do not want `print.judgeit.seats`, `head.judgeit.seats`, etc. to appear in the package index, because it quickly becomes very cluttered.

Comment: The function in a package Index are almost always sorted alphabetically. I don't know if alternate orders are possible.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any easy fix for what you are asking.

### Tags and their effect

`@export` will make your function visible in the global environment. CRAN requires that you document any such functions that is not hidden (i.e. that starts with `.`).

If you use `@describeIn` or `@rdname`, an automatic alias is created. Any alias creates an entry in the index, but points to the same .Rd file. For example, adding

```
#' @name myfunction
#' @aliases foo foobar`
```

would create `foo` and `foobar` entries in the index, but refer to the `myfunction.Rd` documentation file. If you try to delete manually the `\alias{}` in the .Rd file, CRAN will complain.

`@describeIn` will list the functions in the order they appear in the .R files (if they are documented in multiple files, they are listed according to the alphabetical order of the .R file, then the order of appearance). Reordering your functions can give you what you want.

`@keywords internal` (along with `@export`, a title and a description) will have Roxygen create a .Rd file that can be accessed by the user using `?`, but will **not** be visible in the index (if you have only the tags, Roxygen will not create a .Rd file and you will get a warning because your function is not documented).

If you have a `@keywords internal` in any of the functions calling `@describeIn`, that function will be masked from the index. This does not apply to all functions in a .R file, only those which are aliases.

`@usage` requires you to have an alias for each method documented. You can try using instead `@section Usage:`, but note sections are listed in alphabetical order and the spacing will be larger.

### Workaround

If you document a `NULL` function, you can add the `@param` you want. and include a multiple lines `@Section: Usage` field to include (manually) the S3 methods with your comments. Give it a name such as `@name Seats` (it cannot be the name of the function, otherwise you have `?seats` pointing to two different files).

Then, document your function `seats` with a different `@name` tag and a different title, and use `@internal' to hide it from the user. Use` \code{\link{seats}}` to refer to that documentation.

```
#' Seats 
#' Description of the function
#' @param judgeit.object object
#' @param x object from seats
#' @param ... additional arguments
#' @name seats
#' @section Usage:
#' \preformatted{seats(judgeit.object, ...)
#' ## S3 method for class 'judgeit.seats'
#' print(x, ...)
#' ## S3 method for class 'judgeit.seats'
#' head(x, ...)
#' ## S3 method for class 'judgeit.seats'
#' tail(x, ...)}
NULL

#' Seats function
#' @name internal-function
#' @inheritParams seats
#' @export
#' @keywords internal
#' @seealso \code{\link{seats}}
seats <- function(judgeit.object, ...) {
[...omitted...]
class(out.object) <- "judgeit.seats"
return(out.object) 
}

#' Print a \code{\link{seats}} output
#'
#' @inheritParams seats
#' @describeIn internal-function 
#' @export
print.judgeit.seats <- function(x,...) print(x$output,...)
```

This way, the user calling `?seats` will be pointed to the overall documentation.